# Recursive sequence problem (while it oscillates)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The following sequence oscillates

$$a_1 = 1$$
$$a_{n+1} = -(a_n)^2+4a_n-1$$

If its possible to find the limit of a function that oscillates between 2 and 3 (after n = 2), and if so how do we find it?

Comment: I get $a_2=-1-4-1=-6, a_3=-36+24-1=-13$  What am I missing?

Comment: If it oscillates, then it cannot converge

Answer (score 1):

Well of you prove that the limit exists and its value is $L$, then by continuity you have 
$$L=-L^2+4L-1$$
 I.e. $L$ is one of the two solutions of the equation, namely
$$\frac{3\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Again, you can do this after showing that the limit exists.

However in your case (i.e. with your initial value 1) the sequence is      $1,2,3,2,3,2,3,...$ therefore it does not converge. To prove this, you have
$$\lim\sup a_n=3\mbox{ and }\lim\inf a_n=2$$
And because there exist two subsequences (odd and even) converging to different values, the limit does not exist.

Comment: sorry i edited the problem now it was wrong format

Comment: Ok I've edited the answer too.